# Solidity expressed in different languages such as chinese?

Tags: solidity

I refer to the ethereum yellow paper.

"Driving Factors. There are many goals of this project; one key goal is to facilitate transactions between consenting individuals who would otherwise have no means to trust one another. This may be due to
geographical separation, interfacing difficulty, or perhaps
the incompatibility, incompetence, unwillingness, expense,
uncertainty, inconvenience or corruption of existing legal
systems. By specifying a state-change system through a
rich and unambiguous language, and furthermore architecting a system such that we can reasonably expect that
an agreement will be thus enforced autonomously, we can
provide a means to this end."

Say, If I enter a smart contract agreement with someone from china who only reads and writes chinese, both of us needs to be speaking the common language in order to come up and agree on the smart contract.

Can solidity be expressed in multiple languages before it becomes bytecode to be run on EVM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can honestly. Solidity is a programming language and as for all the programming language the keywords are in English.

But, anyway, nobody stops you to write comments for your code in Chinese.

```
// 你好
function hello() public pure returns(string) {
    return '你好';
}
```